# CORS issues with domain address, but working fine with direct ip address and localhost

Tags: javascript, cors, django-cors-headers

I am having a django service hosted on a server which has apis with endpoint http://something.com/api_link

I have a Webapp in react which tries to hit the api http://something.com/api_link. The react webapp is hosted with domain http://somethingother.com and i have enabled CORS at django level to allow all origin to access the api.

But i am seeing a weird behavior :-

**Behavior 1**

whenever i try to hit the api from localhost or direct ip address(from which the domain http://somethingother.com is linked)there is no issue and the api succeeds.

**Behavior 2**

But whenever i tries to hit the api from domain name http://somethingother.com i get this issue in the OPTIONS call of the browser.

**Access to fetch at 'http://something.com/api_link' from origin 'http://somethingother.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

And the difference i noticed in both the cases where that in Request Header of behavior 1 the **Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type**

and

in behavior 2's Request Header the **Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,content-type**

And in the Response Headers of both behavior I get

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with**

I understand that in response header the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** doesn't contains **access-control-allow-origin** but i am not able to understand that how come localhost and even direct ip address are not running into the issue as the domain request is running into.

Why is access-control-allow-origin is getting added when request is from domain and not when the request is from ip Address or localhost.

Here is how i am calling the api from client

```
fetch(" http://something.com/api_link", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    mobile: number
  })
});
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. It's pointless to send it from the client.

Comment: Also nobody can see your code so nobody can tell you how the request headers are being created incorrectly.

Comment: i am not sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin from client it is being added into the request header

Comment: Well if it's being "added to the request header" then you *are* sending it from the client. Again, nobody other than you knows anything about your client-side code, so it's just a complete mystery.

Comment: @Pointy I have added my code from client side.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for that header to be added if that's the code involved. Have you verified with the browser "Network" developer tool that the Request headers really are what you think they are?

Comment: yes they are like that, also the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not being sent in request header it is send as Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access-control-allow-origin as a value to header Access-Control-Allow-Headers not itself as a request header.